# Option Tree default logo

Tags: php, wordpress

I don't understand how I get an default image from theme folder when Option Tree logo is not selected.

```
<div id="logo-section">
            <?php if ( function_exists( 'ot_get_option' ) ) : ?>
            <?php $logo = ot_get_option( 'pp_logo_upload' ); ?>
            <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo $logo; ?>" class="logo" />
            </a>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: explain a bit more with full code details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option Tree accepts a second parameter for [`ot_get_option`](https://github.com/valendesigns/option-tree/blob/master/includes/ot-functions.php#L80) that is the default in case no option is saved.

```
<?php if ( function_exists( 'ot_get_option' ) && ( $logo = ot_get_option( 'pp_logo_upload', 'some-image.png' ) ) != '' ){ ?>
    <div id="logo-section">
        <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>"><img src="<?php echo esc_attr( $logo ); ?>" class="logo" /></a>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: This is right, only you need to end with a closing tag. <?php } ?>